# Show that $Γ$ is isomorphic to $L(V/W,V')$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

**Question**: let $V$, $V'$ be vector spaces over field $K$ and $W$ be subspace of $V$ then show that $\Gamma = \{T\in L(V,V')\vert\forall w\in W: T(w) = 0\}$ is subspace of $L(V,V')$. Further show that this subspace is isomorphic to $L(V/W,V')$ and if $V$, $V'$ are finite dimensional then $\dim\Gamma = (\dim V - \dim W)\dim V'$.

Note: $L(V,V')$ is vector space of all linear transformations from $V$ to $V'$.

**My attempt**: *I had finished the first part*. I had shown that $Γ$ is subspace of $L(V,V')$. Further I can see, $W$ is contained in $\ker T$ for all $T\in L(V,V')$. I know, I need to use isomorphism theorems. But I didn't able to go further. 
Please help me.

Comment: I assume you mean the subspace is isomorphic to $L(V/W,V')$ and not $L(V,V')$.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens sir, yes.

Comment: Yes, but there was a typo which now has been edited out.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: check the (obviously? linear) function
$$f:\Gamma\longrightarrow L(V/W,V′)$$
$$T\longmapsto f(T)$$
$$f(T):V/W\longrightarrow V′$$
$$v + W\longmapsto T(v).$$
Why is well-defined? Why is isomorphism?...

Edit: about the well-definedness of $f(T)$: if $T\in \Gamma$, by definition,
$$\forall w\in W: T(w) = 0.$$
This means that for all $v\in V, w\in W$:
$T(v + w) = T(v)...$

Edit: about the injectivity of $F$ ($[] =$ class of equivalence):

$$f(T) = 0\iff\forall [v]\in V/W:\ T(v) = f(T) = 0\iff T = 0.$$
(why the last $\iff$?)

About the surjectivity: write $V$ as direct sum of $W$ with another subspace (call it $E$). Now taking $S\in L(V/W,V')$, we must define a $\bar S\in\Gamma$ with $f(\bar S) = S$. This means that for $v\in E:\ \bar S(v) =\cdots$

Comment: Sir, how $f$ is defined? What is definition of$f$? and please elaborate.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi, read again. For each $T\in\Gamma$, $f(T)$ is the linear function (check!) from $V/W$ in $V'$ defined by $f(T)(v + W) = T(v)$. Start checking that is well-defined (independent of the representative).

Comment: Sir thanks for adding more details. Sir yes now I can see $f$ is well defined. Further to check injectivity of $f$, I think we just need to check $kerf=\{o\}$ where $o$ is zero element of $L(V/W,V')$. Since $Kerf=\{T\in \Gamma :f(T)=o\}$ and hence $kerf=\{T\in \Gamma: f(T)(v+W)=o(v+W)\}$. $kerf=\{T\in \Gamma: T(v)=0_{V'}\}$ then how to proceed further? and if we prove injectivity then too we need to prove $f$ is surjective and that will more difficult for me because I didn't able to see how for every $T$ in $L(V/W,V')$ there exists element in $\Gamma$. Please help.